# set select option 'selected', by value,but the brower not show selected text

Tags: javascript, jsp, selector

In my jsp pages,I have a select with some options in it. Now i need to make one of those options selected 
I have the following HTML:

```js
document.getElementById('test').options[1].selected='selected'
```

```html
<select id='test'>
 <option value='ruby'>ruby</option>
 <option value='saab'>saab</option>
 <option value='sst'>sst</option>
<select>
```

but the result is in html page,brower can show saab,in jsp pages brower shows ruby(default selected),how can i show selected text by brower in my jsp pages?

Comment: Are you sure this has ANYTHING to do with JSP? this looks like javascript stuff, JSP is **not** javascript

Comment: sorry,this is because I use jquery mobile,so it should be add $(selector).selectmenu('refresh', true);

Comment: That's still jquery, jsp is a web technology for writing web applications in java, not javascript